# Selecting value of zero from raster and assigning new value based on majority of its neighborhood using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

I have a raster layer has values +1, -1, and zero. Now I want to select those pixels whose value is zero and assign them new values based on the majority of its neighbor 5*5 cells.

Is there anyway that I can do this using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

I've tried focal statistics but it is not exactly I want.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a two-step process.

1. Run **[Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Focal_Statistics/009z000000qs000000/)**, using `MAJORITY` as the statistics type. The resulting raster (let's call it's `FocStat`) will be used for reference.
2. Run **[Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/)** (Map Algebra) to filter so only cells that were originally zero will use the Focal Statistics result. Raster calculator expression:  `Con(YourRaster == 0, FocStat, YourRaster)`

   Alternatively you can use the **[Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/)** tool, using the original raster (`YourRaster`) as the true condition, `FocStat` as the false condition, and `Value == 0` as the condition.